# How to customize the generic "Error 5: Access is denied" error message in Window Service created via TopShelf

Tags: c#, windows-services, custom-errors, topshelf

I created a windows service via TopShelf. However, when the service run into error during Start(), it always shows a dialog of "Error 5: Access is denied".

I was wondering if there is a way to customize the error in my code....

```
TopshelfExitCode exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
            x.BeforeInstall(ApplyConfigTransform);
            x.AddCommandLineDefinition(DataServiceHost.ANONYMIZE_NAMES, s => options.Add(DataServiceHost.ANONYMIZE_NAMES, s));
            x.AddCommandLineDefinition(DataServiceHost.PORT_OVERRIDE, s => options.Add(DataServiceHost.PORT_OVERRIDE, s));
            x.Service<DataServiceHost>(s =>
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(name => new DataServiceHost());
                s.WhenStarted(host => host.Start(options));
                s.WhenStopped(host => host.Stop());
                s.WhenShutdown(host => host.LogEvent("Shutdown"));
                s.WhenPaused(host => host.LogEvent("Paused"));
                s.WhenContinued(host => host.LogEvent("Continued"));
                s.WhenSessionChanged((host, scArgs) => host.LogSessionChanged(scArgs));
            });
            x.SetServiceName("service name");
            x.SetDisplayName("service name");
            x.SetDescription("service desc");

            x.EnableServiceRecovery(rc =>
            {
                rc.RestartService(1); // restart the service after 1 minute
                rc.SetResetPeriod(1); // set the reset interval to one day
            });

            x.RunAsLocalSystem();
        });
```